# compiz put to next output does not work in all winsows configurations

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit.
Compiz "Put To Next Output" does not work for windows which were placed/sized with Grid Top or Bottom (Left, Right or full width). The window bounces back to previous location. 
It works well for windows placed Left, Right, Full or not docked to any corner. 
Could be related to nvidia driver I use for my Geforce GTX 550 Ti (version 304.116) but I would like to seek others opinion before I start playing with this driver.

Comment: yeah, I'm having the same issue, will let you know if I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I installed and tried Ubuntu `14.04` on my other laptop to look for differences and noticed that the apt repositories for **compiz-plugins are outdated on `12.04`** and lack some functionality **relevant to this question**, the new version has a `put to previous output` function that comes in handy for a 3+ screen setup. Also, by the new unity keybindings I experienced I can infer that at least someone in canonical is concerned about all these UI issues.

***In spite of that***, the grid continues to work exactly as you described and I confirmed on both my OS versions.

**But I found a workaround**:

Just before you send your window to the next output, `"ungrid" it` by semi-maximizing it to one side <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>lef or right</kbd> and bam!, now you can send it and it wont spring back.
 (I use <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> and the switching feels like a breeze.)

It **works on both** `12.04` and `14.04`

(Now, who knows... maybe this is one of those cases where the responsible developer will protest "it's a feature not a bug!" xD LOL)