# Conflict while moving windows between screens in GNOME with Compiz PUT & Grid plugins

Tags: 14.04, gnome, compiz

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with two screens.
I've enabled Compiz' plugins PUT & Grid simultaneously, have set up a shortcut, say Ctrl+Super+O in Grid to place a window to, e.g. the right corner. When I do so and try to use a combination also set to move window to another screen (Ctrl+Super+') it moves and then automatically jumps back to the corner on the previous screen, whilst I want to move it to the same corner at another one. 
Has anyone encountered with the same problem and knows how to tackle it?

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue.  Seems Grid wants to keep it in the corner it places it in.  Really annoying, there's no other way to move a window from one screen to another.  Did you ever find a solution? Is there a bug report somewhere?  Where would one even go?

Comment: Submitted a bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz-plugins-main/+bug/1504677

Comment: +1 I also have been searching for a solution to this for months!

`CCSM 0.9.12.3`, `Ubuntu 16.04.5`

Comment: [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425982/compiz-put-to-next-output-does-not-work-in-all-winsows-configurations)